# JMeter: Distributed (Remote) Testing: Unable to run tests remotely

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, distributed-testing

I setup a distributed load testing environment using JMeter. I am running a Linux Virtual Machine (CentOS) on my Windows Vista (Host). The Linux VM is the JMeter Master (client). I have a server (Linux CentOS) that is my JMeter Slave (server).

I did the following:

1) Added the following to client (master) jmeter.properties:

```
remote_hosts=172.22.222.22:55501 #IP address of the JMeter Slave
client.rmi.localport=55512
mode=Batch
num_sample_threshold=250
```

2) Added the following to server (slave) jmeter.properties:

```
server_port=55501
server.rmi.localhostname=172.22.222.22
server.rmi.localport=55511
```

3) Added the following to server (slave) jmeter-server:

```
RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.22.222.22
```

4) Then from my Master, I did:

```
ssh -R 55512:localhost:55512 172.22.222.22
```

5) Then I started the jmeter server:

```
sudo ./jmeter-server
```

I got:

```
Using local port: 55511
Created remote object: UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[172.22.222.22:55511](local),objID:[637a4bg5:14185b4361e:-7fff, 894250217845851586]]]
```

6) Then from my Master, I launched the JMeter GUI, and did 
Run --> Remote Start --> 172.22.222.22

I got the following error:

```
2013/10/04 16:03:06 ERROR - jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart: Failed to initialise remote engine java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 172.22.222.22; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.getEngine(ClientJMeterEngine.java:54)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.<init>(ClientJMeterEngine.java:67)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart.doRemoteInit(RemoteStart.java:176)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart.doAction(RemoteStart.java:79)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 26 more
```

Can anyone please help me figure out what I did wrong, and how can I resolve this issue?
I tried turning off iptables on both client and server, but I get the same thing:

```
sudo service iptables stop
sudo chkconfig iptables off
```

Comment: is there a firewall that could be blocking the connection?

Comment: Please check if the port is open, locally and remote. You can take netcat.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue. You need to setup reverse SSH tunnels from master to client for results transfer. Check this: http://rolfje.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/distributed-jmeter-through-vpn-and-ssl/

Answer (score 1):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513679/jmeter-remote-connection-throwing-connection-refused-to-host/23551682#23551682)

I think the only way to work around this is to setup a full featured VPN.