# Jmeter remote connection throwing "Connection refused to host"

Tags: jmeter

I setup a distributed load testing environment using JMeter in unbundu machines.

->Master: the system running JMeter GUI, control each slave.

->Slave: the system running jmeter-server, receive command from the master and send a request to server under test.

->Target: the web server under test, get request from slaves.

### Basic requirements are done:

-The firewalls on the systems are turned off

-All the planned master and Slaves are in the same subnet

-The JMeter server can access the target.

-Same version of JMeter on all the systems (version 2.3.4 ).

### I did the following:

1) Tried pinging form master to slave and vice versa through ubundu terminal. its happening ..

2) Added the following to client (master) jmeter.properties:

```
# Remote hosts and RMI configuration

 remote_hosts=192.168.0.139:1099

# RMI port to be used by the server (must start rmiregistry with same port)

server_port=1099
```

3) Added the following to server (Slave) jmeter.properties:

```
# On the server(s)
 set server_port=1234
 start rmiregistry with port 1234
```

4) Now started the Jmeter engine on Master.

a) Started Jmeter on master machine (GUI)

b) Created test plan--> (added tread group , samplers and required listners)

c)  Now start the Slave(s) from the GUI

```
  -click Run at the top

  -select Remote start

  -select the IP address
```

But error popup came as :-

**"Connection refused to host : 192.168.0.139; nested exception is : java.net.ConnectionException : Connection Refused"**

what may be the reason for not connecting with the remote salve (say here : 192.168.0.139)

DO i need to do any more configuration in jmeter.properties file or in any other files (in both slave and master)?

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: yes. Issue got resolved when started the slave machine buy running jmeter-server.bat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you forgot to start the slave in "slave mode". 
In command line mode, go to jmeter/bin directory and execute  
 jmeter-server.bat

That will start the slave process and will keeps it listening for commands.
Then you can go forward, loading amd launching the script.
have a look at: 
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf

Also be aware that: 
- the two systems MUST run the same Jmeter version 
- the two systems MUST be on the same subnetwork 
- the two systems SHOULD be as similar as possible: same OS, same directory tree, etc 
- "remote_hosts" only require the address. The port is specified by "server_port" parameter.

Comment: if slave is pod in k8s, and controller is outside k8s, and try to connect to slave by nodeip:port, are they on the same subnetwork?

Comment: I don't kno what k8s is.
The point is that master connect to the server in order to start the test BUT also the slaves connect the server (on dynamic ports) to return the samples data.
So, if they are not on the same network, the arrangement can be daunting.
I read of some testin on VPN (which is used to implement the "same network idea", actually), but I never did this personally.